# PHP using List in SOAP Parameter

Tags: php, web-services, soap

This is the SOAP-Service i want to use:
https://powersystem.enertrag.com/PyWebServices/PowerService.asmx?op=GetMonatswerte

This is "my" Code (based on an Example witch i found here):

```
<?php

/* Initialize webservice with your WSDL */
$client = new SoapClient("https://powersystem.enertrag.com/PyWebServices/PowerService.asmx?wsdl");

/* Set your parameters for the request */
$eas = array(
  12,
  47,
  81,
);
$params = array(
  "username" => "Bilbo",
  "password" => "123456",
  "serverUsername" => "Beutlin",
  "serverPassword" => "12345678",
  "eas" => $eas,
  "jahr" => 2014,
);

/* Invoke webservice method with your parameters, in this case: Function1 */
$response = $client->__soapCall("GetMonatswerte", array($params));

/* Print webservice response */
var_dump($response);

?>
```

The Errormassege i get is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Die
>   Anforderung konnte vom Server nicht verarbeitet werden. ---> Fehler
>   bei der ermittlung der Monatswerte. in /var/www/test.php:50 Stack
>   trace: #0 /var/www/test.php(50):
>   SoapClient->__soapCall('GetMonatswerte', Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/test.php on line 50

I think i did something wrong with the parameters, because i used an other Method from the service with less parameters and it worked fine. Specially the "eas" Part from the parameters dont looks good for me.
I read something from class struktures, but in this case the "eas" is a list of machines, so it can be 1 item, 2 items or 100 items.

I hope that someone can show me my mistake.

Thanks